# Unable to mount directory on WSO2 docker instance

Tags: docker

For some reason I'm unable to mount a directory within docker on Linux. The odd thing about this is that I managed to get it working under Docker for Windows, using the same docker image and setup.

The image I'm using is [WSO2 Enterprise Integrator](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2ei-integrator). I'm using version 6.4.0 and try to add my own config from the host machine. I try to run the image using the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 8280:8280 -p 8243:8243 -p 9443:9443 --name integrator --volume /home/ludo/development/docker_config/wso2/conf:/home/wso2carbon/wso2ei-6.4.0/conf wso2/wso2ei-integrator:6.4.0
```

I made sure the settings were done correctly (by using chmod o+r on the entire conf directory) but no matter what I try, I always get the error stating:

> sed: couldn't open temporary file /home/wso2carbon/wso2ei-6.4.0/conf/axis2/sedZmvviu: Permission denied

Note that I tried running this command as the root user as well by sudoing. I made sure during the docker setup that the user as specified (i.e. ludo in this case) was added to the docker group. I have therefore been able to run any other machine, including portainer using data volumes.

I have tried to use both the mount command as well as the volumes for this trick. Essentially I would like overwrite the conf directory on the guest system with the one on my host, making sure I can locally set configuration and ensure config persistence.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is slowly becoming my second Tumbleweed award.....

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that `chmod o+r` only gives the docker user _read_ rights, not _write_ rights. Make sure the user in the docker container is what you think it is and set the right for the folder either to `chmod o+rw` or make the owner/group the same as the docker container or change the userId of the running container (it is set using the USER_ID variable in the Dockerfile)

Comment: @mhogerheijde: Thanks for your reply. In the meantime I have setup this package to run locally without docker. Once I find the time to revisit this part I will make sure to check your suggestion.